# How do I read settings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, settings

I need to read a string from Settings in my C# program. Here is what I did:

1. Right-click on my project and selected "Properties".
2. Clicked on the "Settings" tab.
3. Created a default settings file by clicking on "This project does not contain a default settings file. Click here to create one."
4. Added a new setting with the name=ASHost, type=string, Scope=Application, Value=some. The access modifier for the settings file is "Internal".
5. I clicked on "View Code". Then looked at the namespace which is SI.AS.CommonLogic.ErrorUtils.Properties.

But when I go to my class in the same project and write:

```
SI.AS.CommonLogic.ErrorUtils.Properties.Settings.
```

Then this is as far as IntelliSense will autocomplete. I want it to read/write:

```
SI.AS.CommonLogic.ErrorUtils.Properties.Settings.ASHost
```

What am I missing?

**note:** IntelliSense can't see "Settings" on its own.

**update** "Default doesn't appear with IntelliSense after Settings. Typing

```
SI.AS.CommonLogic.ErrorUtils.Properties.Settings.Default.ASHost
```

manually gives an Invalid token error.

**solved**

Now IntelliSense finally showed Default.ASHost. I changed the "Access Modifier" under the settings tab to "Public".

Comment: What do you mean it can't see `Settings` on its own? Usually you won't have the namespace `using SI.AS.CommonLogic.ErrorUtils.Properties;` on the top so it won't show directly in intellisense. Did you **save** all your files `Ctrl+Shift+S`

Comment: giddy. I suspect that might be the problem (Ctrl+Shift+S). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You change the scope to `User`. Application settings are ReadyOnly.
2. The settings are at:

   ```
   SI.AS.CommonLogic.ErrorUtils.Properties.Settings.Default.ASHost
   ```

Comment: That is good. I want to change it to User, because I have to write to it too. But I still can't access it for either reading or writing. IntelliSense is completely empty after SI.AS.CommonLogic.ErrorUtils.Properties.Settings.

Comment: (1) Can you compile your project and try again. (2) Are you trying to access it outside your app? Since Settings is an internal class.

Comment: Yes. It does work now. It was either the access modifier or saving all files that did it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

```
SI.AS.CommonLogic.ErrorUtils.Properties.Settings.Default.ASHost
```

Comment: I can't access Default either.

Answer (score 1):

Almost there. You missed `Default`.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.<Your_Setting_Name>
```

Comment: I think he meant that he *has* intellisense on settings. But he wants to have his defined settings appear in intellisense.

Comment: Which should appear... I just checked (in VS 2010)

Comment: There is no default after SI.AS.CommonLogic.ErrorUtils.Properties.Settings.

Comment: Restart VS and see if the problem is gone. Sometimes intellisense gets messed up. + Have you changed any settings on VS which might cause intellisense to not work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Just as an addition to what everyone else has said, the `Settings` class is generated at compile time. So you will need to compile at least once after adding new settings before the setting will show up in Intellisense.